# How to change abs() or sqrt()?

Tags: python, gurobi, absolute-value

I want to change |y-R*p|

```
abs(y[i]-R*p[i])
```

I thought

```
sqrt((y[i]-Rp[i])* (y[i]-R*p[i]))
```

I used model.addConstr

```
for i in P:
   model.addConstr(sqrt((y[i]-R*p[i])*(y[i]-R*p[i])) == E[i],name="absconstr" %i)
Type Error:must be real number, not gurobipy.QuadExpr
```

I used model.addConstrAbs.

```
for i in P:
 model.addGenConstrAbs(E[i],y[i]-R*p[i],"absConstr")
AttributeError: 'gurobipy.LinExpr' object has no attribute '__cindex__'
```

```
for i in P:
  model.addGenConstrAbs(E,y[i]-R*p[i],"absConstr")
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__cindex__'
```

I cannot move the problem.
What should I do?

Comment: You do know, that ``abs`` means absolute, and ``sqrt`` means squareroot, right?

Comment: @Karina: abs(x) = sqrt(x*x) for real numbers x.

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? I don't understand it. If you have a custom class that you want to be able to call `abs()` on, define an `__abs__` method for it: https://blog.finxter.com/python-__abs__/

Comment: @Ry oh yes, sure, stupid me lol. I guess the ``{ }`` got my attention more than the math

Comment: What are the types of `y` and `Rp`?

Comment: I want to change in gurobi py

Comment: y is a natural number.  R is a decimal number.  P is a natural number

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [gurobipy documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_agc_abs.html), you may want to try:

```
model.addGenConstrAbs(x, y[i]-R*p[i], "absconstr")
```

Comment: I want to change dictionary. what should I do? I use it in objective  function

Comment: I've never used gurobi, only read the documentation to point you in the right direction. I guess you need to convert your variables to the types that are allowed in the addGenConstrAbsfunction. Can you convert the values of your dictionary to a list using `list(d.values())`?

Comment: model.addGenConstrAbs(E,y[i]-R*p[i],"absConstr")                                                                            'dict' object has no attribute '__cindex__'

Comment: I cannnot do it. I'm glad to change the answer